# Why app component not being returned correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having problem with my App component not being returned properly, apparently.

App.jsx:

```
     import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
     import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
     import UsersList from './components/UsersList';
     import AddUser from './components/AddUser';
     import About from './components/About';
     import axios from 'axios';


       const App = () => {      
    9 
   10     const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
   11     const [isUsername, setUsername] = useState('');
   12     const [isEmail, setEmail] = useState('');
   13     
   14     
   15     const getUsers = () => {
   16         axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/users`).then((res) => {
   17             setUsers(res.data.data.users); }).catch((err) => {console.log(err); });
   18     }
   19   
   20     const handleSubmit = e => {
   21         e.preventDefault(); 
   22         const data = {   
   23             username: isUsername,           
   24             email: isEmail  
   25         };               
   26 
   27         axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/users`, data)
   28             .then(res => {  
   29                 console.log(res);               
   30                 getUsers(); 
   31                 setEmail('');
   32                 setUsername('');                
   33             }).catch(err => {console.log(err)} );
   34     };
   35 
   36     const handleChange = e => {
   37         if(e.target.name === 'email') { 
   38         setEmail(e.target.value);       
   39         } else {
   40         setUsername(e.target.value);    
   41         }
!  42     };
   43 
   44     useEffect(() => {
   45         getUsers();
   46     }, [])

          return (
   29         <section className='section'>   
   28             <div className='container'>     
   27                 <div className='columns'>       
!  26                     <div className='column is-half'>
   25                         <br />
!  24                         <Switch>
!  23                             <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
!  22                                 <>
!  21                                 <h1 className='title is-1'>All Users</h1>
!  20                                 <hr /><br />
!  19                                 <AddUser
!  18                                     email={isEmail}
!  17                                     username={isUsername}
!  16                                     handleChange={handleChange}
!  15                                     handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
+  14                                 />
+  13                                 <hr /><br />
+  12                                 <UsersList users={users} />
+  11                                 </>
+  10                             )} />
+   9                             <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
+   8                         </Switch>
    7                     </div>
    6                 </div>
    5             </div>
    4         </section>
    3     )
    2  };
    1 
   79  export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App'; 
 
reportWebVitals();       
 
ReactDOM.render((<Router><App /></Router>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

AddUser.jsx:

```
    import React from 'react'; 
  1                            
  2 
  3 const AddUser = props => { 
  4     return (               
  5         <form onSubmit={e => props.handleSubmit(e) }>
  6             <div className='field'>       
  7                 <input
  8                     name='username'
  9                     className='input is-large'
 10                     type='text'
 11                     placeholder='Enter a username'
 12                     onChange={e => props.handleChange(e)}
 13                     value={props.username}
 14                     required
 15                 />
 16             </div>         
 17             <div className='field'>         
 18                 <input     
 19                     name='email'
 20                     className='input is-large'
 21                     type='email'
 22                     placeholder='Enter email'
 23                     onChange={e => props.handleChange(e)}
 24                     value={props.email}
 25                     required
 26                 />
 27             </div>
 28             <input         
 29                 type='submit'
 30                 className='button is-primary is-large is-fullwidth'
 31                 value='Submit'
 32             />
 33         </form>
 34     )
 35 };
 36 
 37 export default AddUser;
```

About.jsx:

```
      import React from 'react';
    1                          
+   2 const About = () => (
+   3     <div>                
+   4         <h1 className='title is-1'>About</h1>
+   5         <hr /><br />     
+   6         <p>About Page</p>
+   7     </div>               
+   8 );
+   9 
+  10 export default About;
```

UsersList.jsx:

```
    import React from 'react';  
    1                          
    2 
    3 const UsersList = props => {
    4     
    5     return (             
    6         <div>            
    7             {            
    8             props.users.map((user) => {     
    9                 return (
+  10                     <React.Fragment>                
   11                     <h4  
   12                     key={user.id}
   13                     className='box title is-4'
   14                     >{ user.username }</h4>
+  15                     </React.Fragment>               
   16                 )        
   17             })           
   18             }
   19         </div>
   20     )
   21 };
   22 
   23 export default UsersList;
```

Error output:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

I see nothing wrong with how I'm exporting the App component or anything wrong with the how I'm returning it. Syntantically it appears OK. I've tried to add `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` in case the app isn't being returned properly because I've got few elements there that needs to be wrapped in the fragment. That made no difference.

Note please I've got no render method because all my components are
function-based hence no render method.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you read *all* of the error message? It says to "Check the render method of `App`." not check how `App` is exported. This means something wasn't imported correctly that `App` is rendering. You need to check your component imports against how they are exported. FYI, the *entire* function body of React function components is considered the "render" function, the return being what you want to "render". Can you edit to include the imports, and add how your components are exported?

Comment: @DrewReese  I've added imports and components being imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicated your code into a codesandbox and with version 6.0.2 of `react-router-dom` installed I see the same exact error as you've specified above. When I specify the latest v5.3.0 version the app renders without issue.

[image]

[image: Edit why-app-component-not-being-returned-correctly]

The issue that RRDv6 no longer exports a `Switch` component (*replaced by a `Routes` component*), and this is the import your code was using and having an issue with.

Reverting back to RRDv5 (`npm un -s react-router-dom; npm i -s react-router-dom@5.3.0`) will fix the issue, or you can follow the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) docs to swap in the correct components from `react-router-dom` v6.

Comment: I didn't consider breaking changes in versions of dependencies. Thank you for pointing that out.